# How to speed up a simple join query in Firebird 2.5.1

Tags: sql, firebird

When executing a simple inner join query on two large tables the result is returned after several seconds in Firebird 2.5.1 In other databases the result is returned after several milliseconds. The question is how to speed up this query and why is Firebird using A NATURAL instead of the index?

The query is:

```
SELECT FIRST 20 * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID;
```

Resulting plan is:

```
PLAN JOIN (A NATURAL, B INDEX (IDX_B_1))
```

Statistics:

[image: Statistics]

Table and index metadata:

```
CREATE TABLE "A" 
(
  "ID"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "PK_A" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);


CREATE TABLE "B" 
(
  "ID"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "AID"  INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT "PK_B" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);


CREATE INDEX "IDX_B_1" ON "B"("AID");
```

To populate you can use this procedure:

```
declare variable nba integer;
declare variable nbb integer;
declare variable nbc integer;

begin
  nba = 0;
  nbb = 0;
  nbc = 0;
  while (nba < 100000) do begin
    insert into A (ID) values (:nba);
    nbc = 0;
    while (nbc < 50) do begin
      insert into B (ID, AID)
      values (:nbb, :nba);
      nbb = nbb + 1;
      nbc = nbc + 1;
    end
    nba = nba + 1;
  end
end
```

Comment: I did this on my SuperServer on Windows 64 and without updating the statistics of the indices I got plan `PLAN JOIN (B NATURAL, A INDEX (PK_A))` which executed in 0.080s. After updating statistics I got plan `PLAN JOIN (A NATURAL, B INDEX (IDX_B_1))` which executed in 0.020s. Make sure your index statistics are uptodate. BTW: Is there any reason you don't define a foreign key from B to A?

Comment: Your actual plan and execution details, especially rows affected seem to suggest you are not actually doing a `SELECT FIRST 20`.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'll try to recreate your situation with Firebird Superserver and Windows 64 to see if i can get the same results. Currently we are using a 32 bit version and Superclassic

Comment: There is btw no reason for not defining a foreign key. I didn't think it was nessecary for the question.

Comment: If the numbers continue being high, try using a different tool to execute (eg Flamerobin, or plain ISQL), maybe your tool is simulating `FIRST 20` (that would be weird, but who knows).

Comment: Increase page buffers for your database. Use minimum 1000 with ClassicServer and tens of thousands with SuperServer. Depends on available memory.

Comment: Always update indices statistics before checking actual plan. Do backup/restore cycle in order to recalculate all indices in the database.

Comment: @AndrejKirejeŭ I tested with superserver defaults, so that doesn't matter for this.

Comment: The problem was the tooling. I've tried with Flamerobin and got equal results. 20 ms Thanks for the help.